# Accessing files on external server

Tags: php

Is there any way to access files of Third party server using PHP?

Comment: **Definitely not**. With little exception, there are no remote *files*, but resources of various types, accessed by means of some **protocol**. Talking of protocols would be much more correct than of "files".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just fopen them if url_fopen is enabled, or use CURL.

Comment: Doesn't matter. see my example. you can pass any URL - no matter if it's a plain string, a function return value, a variable containing an URL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way - assuming url_fopen_wrappers are enabled - is simply using `file_get_contents()` with a remote (http://, ftp://) URL.

If you don't want to rely on them being enabled, use CURL - while it requires a PHP extension it's pretty common so chances are high it's enabled even on shared hosting.

Here are examples for both methods:

```
// using url_fopen_wrappers
$contents = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');

// using CURL
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://stackoverflow.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Now i get that site but if i have password and user name .Can i log in?

Comment: Yes, use `http://username:password@yoururl.com/...`. When using curl, set CURLOPT_USERPWD to 'username:password'.

Comment: If i have user name ,pass,url in my db.Can,i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you could even use copy('thirdPartyFileUrl', 'fileO')